# Take specific data from a list

Tags: rush

```
1|FHCT1024|TEE SZEN YONG
2|FHCT1024|LIM JIN CHONG
3|FHCT1024|CHEN JING WEN
4|FHCT1024|YIP JING YEAP
5|FHCT1024|CHEAH YONG NEE
1|FHSB1214|TEE SZEN YONG
2|FHSB1214|LIM JIN CHONG
3|FHSB1214|CHEN JING WEN
4|FHSB1214|YIP JING YEAP
```

I have this kind of list, but I just want to take only the name out of the list.

How can I do that?

Comment: Need more info. Can you provide a sample of how to create that list?

Comment: It is just written in a notepad, and I am using open() function to read this notepad. Now I suffering with how to take only the name from this list and print it out. I just want the name to be shown.